# Error: var is a reserved word - React native

Tags: android, react-native

I have made a simple ListView in React Native. I am getting an error as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgaW6.png). I searched the Internet but couldn't find relevant posts. The code is provided below.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {StyleSheet, View, AppRegistry, ListView, Text} from "react-native";

class dhrumil extends Component{

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowsHasChanged : (r1,r2) => r1!==r2})
return {
dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(["1","2","3","4","5"])
};
}
}

_renderer(rowData){
  return <Text>{rowData}</Text>;
}

render(){
return(
<ListView
dataSource = {() => this.state.dataSource}
renderRow = {() => this._renderer()}
/>
);


}

}
AppRegistry.registerComponent("dhrumil",()=>dhrumil);
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Your object literal syntax is wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the wrong coding in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowsHasChanged : (r1,r2) => r1!==r2})
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(["1","2","3","4","5"])
    };
}
```